# Why this function is not working?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-routing

I created function for my blog.

Model -

```
public function get_article($nosaukums) {
    $query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM ieraksti WHERE virsraksts = :nosaukums')
            ->parameters(array(':nosaukums' => $nosaukums))->execute();
    return $query;
}
```

Controller -

```
public function action_article()
{
    Route::set('article', 'article/(name)', array('name' => '.+'))
            ->defaults(array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'article',

            ));
        $this->template->content = View::factory('index/article')
                ->set('query', Model::factory('index')->get_article($nosaukums));
}
```

and view -

```
<?php
foreach($nosaukums as $article)
{
    echo '<h3>'.$article['virsraksts'].'</h3>';
}
?>
```

I want to url - domain.com/article/name_of_article, but domain.com/article is not working - error `HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL article was not found on this server.` Why I get this error?

Comment: you probably should say method instead of function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Setting up the route in controllers action is a bad idea - move it to the bootstrap.php
2. Change the route to:

   ```
   Route::set('article', 'article(/<name>)', array('name' => '.+'))
       ->defaults(array(
           'controller' => 'index',
           'action' => 'article',
   ));
   ```
3. In your controller you should get article name using `$this->request->param('name')` (this is probably what you should assign to your `$nosaukums` variable, because it is undefined in your code)

Answer (score 1):

Error 404 means it doesn't exist.  This seems more like a mod_rewrite problem than a code problem (at least, with the current details given).  Check your web server logs to see what page the server is actually trying to load.